# callback for two topics at the same time

Tags: ros, callback, message-filters, message-filter, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I would like to save an image from a depthcamera and a webcam at the same time as a mouse click.
So I subscribed to the depth image and in this callback I used

```
 webcam_image = ros::topic::waitForMessage<Image>("/logitech_usb_webcam/image_raw");
```

but it seems that the wait for message skips the first message and uses the second one instead...

So I went on and tried another solution. Therefore, I used the registerCallback function from the message_filter package but it doesn't behave like I want it because the callback gets never triggered (both topics are published).

My code looks like this

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>


using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;


void sync_callback(const ImageConstPtr& depth_image, const ImageConstPtr&  webcam_image){

        ROS_INFO("syncro callback");
}

  

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;

        message_filters::Subscriber<Image> depth_sub(nh, "/camera/depth/image", 1);
        message_filters::Subscriber<Image> webcam_sub(nh, "/logitech_usb_webcam/image_raw", 1);
        TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image> sync(depth_sub, webcam_sub, 50);
        sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&sync_callback, _1, _2));



        ros::spin();
        return 0;
}
```

Would be great to get your help to get this working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47406/callback-for-two-topics-at-the-same-time/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TimeSynchronizer requires that the timestamps in the messages to be synchronized match exactly. Since you are trying to sync images from two separate cameras that, based on the topic names, are likely not synchronized, their timestamps will not match perfectly. That is why you never get any synchronized image callbacks.

Take a look at http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy for approximate time synchronization.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-11-04**:
A similar node that works is at http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/trac/stingray/browser/trunk/sync_images, where I used the approximate time synchronizer that Eric referenced.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-11-04**:
thanks a lot to both of you for the good advice...